# create a fixed height and width for profile photos

Tags: users, user-profile, profile

Is it possible to do anything with Craft's `getPhotoUrl()` function to allow images to be processed in a similar way like assets?

For example for our profile photos I'd like them to be returned 45x45 cropped from centre.

Currently if a user were to upload a landscape photo they would see something like 45x25 because the height isn't being maintained.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.  They currently aren't technically true "Assets" like in the rest of Craft.

The most you can do is pass in a size to the method `getPhotoUrl(45)` and you'll get a 45 x 45 square result back.  I believe it will crop from the center only.

We have plans for Craft 3 so they'll be treated like 1st class Assets and you'll be able to perform transforms on them like any other Asset.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brad but it doesnt actually crop it as you describe.  It does maintain a aspect ratio as i mentioned above as this is the first thing i tried.

Comment: I could be wrong about that... will clarify with @andris.

Comment: I assume this is all in the context of a front-end entry form, no?  In the CP, you get an actual cropper modal to use.

Comment: Correct, we're just printing the user photo and we want it to be 64x64 from the centre as you described above.

Comment: Has 2.5 managed to rectify this yet? Can we use transforms on user photos?